# Async php function to backup database

Tags: php, asynchronous, server, cron

I am using a PHP page to backup my database and it works just perfectly.

My problem (my future problem, Id better say) is that my `cron job` in my hosting allows working function only if a response is returned by 5 seconds, otherwise it fails.

My DB so far is quite small and I am not sure how much time it takes but surely less than 5 seconds since it is working.

But when my db will grow up, I reckon issues will start.

How can I make my function working also after 5 seconds?

With an async function will I solve?

Comment: Don't your host have some tool to back up your database for you? If they don't, they aren't much of a host.

Comment: Possibly: find a better host? If you can only run cron code for 5 seconds then it doesn't matter *how* you do it, if it takes longer than 5 seconds it takes longer than you're allowed to.

Comment: It is written "HTTP Cron requests have a timeout of 5seconds (maximum time of waiting)". It is what I meant, isn'it? So far it takes 1.52 seconds and it is quite small. Let's wait when it will be much bigger

Comment: That sounds more like any http request you make through cron will time out after 5 sec (if it doesn't manage to connect to a host within 5 sec). Test it by adding`sleep(10);` in the top of your current cron. If it still works, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: The idea of sleep(10) has been a great idea to assess the function. So, I used a sleep(15) followed by a  file_gets_content(). The cronjob returned error 500 but the file has been written anyway after 15 seconds. Should I rely this system for the future?

Answer (score 1):

hm, do you have shell access?
i made my index.php and its called master class to detect cli mode. like so:

```
if( php_sapi_name() === 'fpm-fcgi') {
    define( 'WEB_MODE', true );
    define( 'CLI_MODE', false );
} else if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    define( 'WEB_MODE', false );
    define( 'CLI_MODE', true );
} else {
    define( 'WEB_MODE', true );
    define( 'CLI_MODE', false );
}
```

then in my script which is executed by http request i do it like so:

```
$this->asyncShellExecution('/usr/bin/php ' . ROOT_PATH .'/php/index.php -m houseKeeping' );

private function asyncShellExecution(string $str)
{
    exec($str .  " > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
}
```

in cli mode i call new asyncHouseKeeping()

```
class asyncHouseKeeping
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $args=getopt("m:t:i:o:l:s:f:");

        if($args['m'] == 'houseKeeping') {
            $this->doHouseKeeping();
        } else {
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

that way i am getting the cpu and time critical image optimization process after uploading images by xhr out of the blocking code and it runs it stuff afterwards.